# Complex SQL Query laravel Build

Tags: laravel

How would I use query builder in Laravel to generate the following SQL statement:

```
    SELECT MAX(QTE) FROM (SELECT SUM(activity_sale_report.quantity_sold) 
    AS QTE FROM activity_sale_report 
    GROUP BY activity_sale_report.activity_id) AS T
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I try this:                                  $posts->leftJoin('products', 'activity_sale_report.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                
               ->select(DB::raw('max(QTE) as qte'))
                     ->withCount([
'activity_sale_report AS QTE' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(activity_sale_report.quantity_sold AS QTE '))->groupBy('activity_sale_report.activity_id');
        }
    ])
               
            ->sum(('SUM(activity_sale_report.quantity_sold AS QTE '))

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using the query builder and not models you can use raw queries

```
$query = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT MAX(QTE) FROM (SELECT SUM(activity_sale_report.quantity_sold) AS QTE FROM activity_sale_report GROUP BY activity_sale_report.activity_id) AS T);
```

I would recommend using the eloquent models, it's easier.